# Does Multiple NSURLConnection make delay of performance?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue

I made a multi files downloader.
I implemented NSURLConnection using NSOperationQueue.

NSOpetationQueue has many NSURLConnection operations.

and, set MaxConcurrentOperationCount to 10.

I thought my code is right, But after run the project, it was wrong.
there are some connection error has occured.
files url were right. and file download was completed. 
but downloading files, occur "timed out" error.

It is so serious. 
I tested it with 8 files, and those total size is only 3M.
But total download time is 2minutes ~!!!

one file download spends only a few second. (2~3 s)
but multi files download occur many overburden!! (2 minutes)

I don't know why it is...
Do Anyone know what reason is?

Comment: Are you testing this on a stable WiFI network or over a cellular connection?

Comment: I was in my Lab. There is a stable WiFi. I think I don't know operation of NSOperationQueue perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, my mistake~!!!

It is not problem.
I checked network speed. and file exist in directory via simulator.

As a result, It depends on network speed !
one file, multi file is the same result.

I'm sorry about wrong question.